# Formula with if text equal

Tags: excel, vba, autofill

I would like to pass from this situation,

[image]

to this:

[image]

I was thinking on: `A2=IF(B2="*Plan*";A1;B2)` but it does not work.

Comment: You can use `LEFT` to check if the cell's left 4 characters are "Plan".

Comment: Or `ISNUMBER(SEARCH())` if the word is not always on the left.